# Can user-mode Linux be compiled and run on UNIX systems?

Tags: linux, virtualization, bsd, sandbox

e.g. on NetBSD or Solaris? Or does it require exclusively Linux-specific system calls, virtual filesystems, etc.?

Also, if it's currently limited to Linux, what changes would be required to port it to a UNIX OS?

Edit: the reason this is on Superuser is that I was considering it as a way to run a Linux guest system on BSD, for desktop use.

Edit 2: the "user-mode Linux" I refer to is not the GNU userland, but a port of the Linux kernel to Linux (see the [user mode Linux wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-mode_Linux#Integration_into_the_Linux_kernel) for details)

(And from that page it does look like kernel support is required for it to be effective, still not quite sure though?)

Comment: What precisely do you mean with user mode Linux? What mostly is done is running a GNU environment on top of the Linux kernel (and linux is just that, a kernel, not a whole OS). And  then we commonly call the whole a linux distribution.

Comment: As to BSD's: At least FreeBSD has a linux emulation mode where you can run  linux-only programs (e.g. a CS server).

Comment: User-mode Linux is a port of the Linux kernel to the Linux userspace. A kernel compiled with ARCH=um will run as a userspace program, and sandbox programs running under it within its own namespace. I'll update my question with a link.